# image not visible wtih thymeleaf and spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am using thymeleaf with spring boot. I tried displaying an image using th:src, but it is not visible. I have saved the images in /resources/static/images folder(I am using STS). Can someone suggest a possible reason for this?? Here is some of the code:

```
<div class="featurette">
        <img class="featurette-image pull-right" th:src="@{/images/browser-icon-chrome.png}" />
        <h2 class="featurette-heading">First featurette headling. <span class="muted">It'll blow your mind.</span></h2>
        <p class="lead">Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper.
            Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo.</p>
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: paste screenshot of directory structure where you kept images.

Comment: @Alien .... done

Comment: go to browser console and check the url for not found image in network tab, from which it is trying to get image.

Comment: I checked, the url was localhost:8080/images/browser-icon-chrome.png .... so I even tried changing the url to /static/images/browser-icon-chrome.png and to /resources/static/images/browser-icon-chrome.png in the img tag, but it made no difference.

Comment: paste this in browser and you should get the image http://localhost:8080/fullstackapp/resources/images/browser-icon-chrome.png or http://localhost:8080/resources/images/browser-icon-chrome.png

Comment: nope...not getting it

Comment: Hey, were you able to figure something out??? It is not just the images url, infact this is happening with all urls, even when I try referencing the bootstrap css file in <link> from the local jar, it does not apply it, but when I mention the absolute web link, it does.